# Spearman correlation with corrwith python

Tags: python, pandas, correlation

I am correlating two data frames using the code below. basically, choosing set of columns from one data frame (a) and one column from the other data frame (b). It works perfectly, except I would need to do it with a spearman's option. I would appreciate any input or ideas. Thank  you...

```
 a.ix[:,800000:800010].corrwith(b.ix[:,0])
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Consider using [pandas.Series.corr](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.corr.html) in an dataframe `apply` where you pass each column into a function, here the anonymous `lambda`, and pair each with the `b` column:

Random data *(seeded to reproduce)*

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(50)

a = pd.DataFrame({'A':np.random.randn(50),
                  'B':np.random.randn(50),
                  'C':np.random.randn(50),
                  'D':np.random.randn(50),
                  'E':np.random.randn(50)})

b = pd.DataFrame({'test':np.random.randn(10)})
```

Reproducing Pearson correlation

```
pear_result1 = a.ix[:,0:5].corrwith(b.ix[:,0])
print(pear_result1)
# A   -0.073506
# B   -0.098045
# C    0.166293
# D    0.123491
# E    0.348576
# dtype: float64

pear_result2 = a.apply(lambda col: col.corr(b.ix[:,0], method='pearson'), axis=0)
print(pear_result2)
# A   -0.073506
# B   -0.098045
# C    0.166293
# D    0.123491
# E    0.348576
# dtype: float64

print(pear_result1 == pear_result2)
# A    True
# B    True
# C    True
# D    True
# E    True
# dtype: bool
```

Spearman correlation

```
spr_result = a.apply(lambda col: col.corr(b.ix[:,0], method='spearman'), axis=0)
print(spr_result)
# A   -0.018182
# B   -0.103030
# C    0.321212
# D   -0.151515
# E    0.321212
# dtype: float64
```

Spearman coefficient with pvalues

```
from scipy.stats import spearmanr, pearsonr

# SERIES OF TUPLES (<scipy.stats.stats.SpearmanrResult> class)
spr_all_result = a.apply(lambda col: spearmanr(col, b.ix[:,0]), axis=0)

# SERIES OF FLOATS
spr_corr = a.apply(lambda col: spearmanr(col, b.ix[:,0])[0], axis=0)
spr_pvalues = a.apply(lambda col: spearmanr(col, b.ix[:,0])[1], axis=0)
```

Comment: That is perfect parfait...in fact, i can still apply my original column selection for data frame...it would be like this with your example: (a.ix[:,0:5]).apply(lambda col: col.corr(b.ix[:,0], method='pearson'), axis=0)......thank you!!

Comment: I just realized....is there an easy way to generate pvalues here...? without having to use scipy.stats.......And if I have to use scipy.stats, do you know by any chance, how I can apply the same framing you just worked out to the...thanks..

Comment: Works great!...thanks both ways. It does not seem I have much of reputation to increase your points...I did the check!